# CouchDB Push data to external API when changed

Tags: rest, notifications, couchdb

We are working on a POC where we have our CouchDB instance and a pouchDB for each user.
We need to read the data from CouchDB use it in our CRM systems.We wanted to achieve this thorugh API where couch can post data to RestAPI and we take it forward from there.

Scenario:
seperate DB for each user

User1 - submits form and the data goes to couchDB

User2 - submits form and the data goes to CouchDB

Now we need to get the data from Couch whenever any inserts/updates to any database.
We had checked Change Notifications but that is something for one database.
In our case each user submits form will be a seperate database.So Can anyone throw some light on getting data out of CouchDB when any inserts/updates.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the details of your data and the general concepts of your app its not easy to give a good advice.
If the data for each user is independent and you just want to collect the data later at in one database, you could consider using a filtered replication.
You can find more information here https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Replication#Filtered_Replication

If data must be merged or other advanced processing, you have to write a script to listen to the changes feeds of all user databases and if something changes do your logic to merge and write to the central database. 
But beware you're kinda building your own sync protocol then which requires careful planning and experience.

Comment: Thanks Tobias for the information. Actually as said, we dont want to merge the data to couchDB into single database. Each user data will be in one database. But what we need is, how to get the data from CouchDB to our RestAPI when any inserts/updates.

Comment: There had been people writing couchdb plugins for that. 
https://github.com/davidoccam/couch_dbupdates
https://github.com/ocastalabs/couchdb_task_handler

I don't have experiences with those plugins. Nor do I know if they are still maintained.

As long as you don't have many users and experience any performance problems I would consider using a small nodejs script as a connector to listen to all changes feeds.
This one might come handy for the implementation:   
https://github.com/iriscouch/follow

Comment: Thanks Tobias. Will look into this.